# What word or phrase do you use in American English for going to someone's place on foot to take them somewhere?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What word or phrase do you use in American English for going to someone's place on foot to take them somewhere? I am aware that when you go to the person's place by car than you use *pick up* Can *pick up* be used for going to someone's place on foot?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope I don't see that meaning reflected in a dictionary, but I think it could be used in that sense, especially if a group on foot were to "pick up" another walker. Maybe someone with a better dictionary could find the meaning.

Comment: You can pick someone up on foot. We have had this before, sometime in 2018 I think.

Comment: @Dmytro O'Hope More context would be useful. Do you intend to use it in a sentence? If so, what is it? That might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the concept of 'take them' presumes a vehicle, even a bicycle or motorcycle. If you are merely walking somewhere together, you are just meeting them. If you are going somewhere that they don't know about, you could say you are 'showing them' - as in "I walked to Joe's house so I could show him how to get to the dog park."